# Best practice for creating mobile(ios, android) app artifact for non-prod and prod environments

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, mobile, deployment

I need to create a mobile app artifact for multiple env. The goal is to promote the same artifact across multiple envs (dev, qa, preprod and prod). The mobile artifact uses a saas url which changes from env to env. Please let me know the best practice to do so.

Currently when the artifact passes qa I create another artifact for pre-prod and finally for prod which is time-consuming and prone to mistakes.

I am thinking of creating an active env url and release version api. What is the best practice?

Thanks,

Comment: make one artifact and have the implementation pass through the URL

Comment: One more thing to add, I am using expo for generating builds.
I am also thinking along the same lines as mentioned in the comment above, my only concern is, this way I need to maintain the client version and the URL it should be pointing too which can be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I think **android-flavors** will solve your problem.

I look like these examples below.

```
  flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors{
        dev{
            applicationId "com.amitgupta.trust_app_android.dev"
        }
        staging{
            applicationId "com.amitgupta.trust_app_android.staging"
        }
        qa{
            applicationId "com.amitgupta.trust_app_android.qa"
        }
        production{
            applicationId "com.amitgupta.trust_app_android.production"
        }

    }
```

You make also use different URLs based on Different environment.

```
flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        QA {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://qa.com/api/"'
        }
        production {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://production.com/api/"'
        }
    }
```

Please, look at these for its implementation.

https://medium.com/@hsmnzaydn/configuration-product-flavors-and-build-variants-in-android-bb9e54d459af

https://www.journaldev.com/21533/android-build-types-product-flavors

For iOS:
You can make use of **Schemes** and **Build** configurations in Xcode. Here's the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/BasingBuildConfigurationsonConfigurationFiles.html

I hope this will be of any help.

Comment: It seems similar to gradle, I need prod url at runtime when the app is published in the app store, not for build time. I only want one artifact for all of my envs so that when the QA passes the build I can promote the same artifact to prod. The same artifact now needs to point to prod backend instead of qa backend.

Comment: hmm, in the above solution you can use one artifact i.e one applicationid and  can manage different URLs but you will be having different release apps for dev, QA, production, etc.

Comment: For different stakeholders(qa,staging,prod etc users) you will be having apps pointing different server/urls , but the point is all different  apps will be same only where pointing server is different. So, If QA app is Ok, it means others are Ok too. So, I think,  in this way you can achieve about what you are talking about i.e " when the QA passes the build I can promote the same artifact to prod.". You are achieving this by using "android-flavors", your artifact is same but your build/app is different.

Hope, I have made my point clear.

Answer (score 0):

The following is true if you use gradle:

1. For top level build.gradle, define appId parameter:

```
allprojects {
    ext {
        appId = 'com.my.app'
    }
}
```

2. For app module's build.gradle, define flavors and use the above parameter:

```
android {
    def globalConfig = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationId globalConfiguration["appId"] + ".dev"
            ...
            buildConfigField "String", "YOUR_ENDPOINT", "\"https://my.dev.env/\""
        }
        qa {
            applicationId globalConfiguration["appId"] + ".qa"
            ...
            buildConfigField "String", "YOUR_ENDPOINT", "\"https://my.qa.env/\""
        }
}
```

3. Build app using specific flavor + use BuildConfig.YOUR_ENDPOINT in code.

Comment: Gradle is for build time. I only want one artifact for all of my envs so that when the qa passes the build I can promote the same build to prod. The same artifact now needs to point to prod backend instead of qa backend.